# Not accessing the Controller functions and resulting 404 page not found error in CI 3

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I installed CI 3 and added my Controller and Model files of previous version which is already renamed.I had gone through the files,filenames first letter are in Uppercase.
On running the site on localhost ie- `http://localhost:81/sitename/` it displays the home page.
But when Controller name and its function name is accompanied on the url ie- `http://localhost:81/sitename/login` it results

> 404 Page not found
>   The page you requested was not found.

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

config.php

```
    $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:81/sitename/';

    $config['index_page'] = '';
   $config['uri_protocol']  = 'REQUEST_URI'; //tried with AUTO also
```

routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'member';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

autoload.php
I have mentioned the url helper

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'file');
```

Controller Member.php

```
<?php 
class Member extends CI_Controller {

    private $controller = '';
    private $data = array();
    private $base_layout = '';

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        // $this->load->library('input');
        $this->load->library('email');
        $this->load->model('member_model');
        $this->controller = strtolower(__CLASS__);
        $this->base_layout = 'layouts/main_content';
        $this->is_logged();
    }

    function is_logged() {
        if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in'))      

            $this->base_layout = 'layouts/login';
            $this->load->view('layouts/login');
    }
 }
```

Controller Login.php

```
<?php 

class Login extends CI_Controller {

    private $controller = '';

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->controller = strtolower(__CLASS__);
        $this->load->model('login_model');

        $this->is_logged();
    }

   public function index() {
        $this->load->view('layouts/login');
    } 

    function is_logged() {
        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Singapore');
        $sess_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');

        if($sess_data) {
            if($sess_data['user_type']=="pre"){
            $c_time = mktime();
            //$c_time = date('h:i:s a');
            $open = strtotime('Today 10am');
            $close = strtotime('Today 8pm');

            if ($c_time > $open && $c_time < $close) {
                redirect('member', 'refresh');
            } else {
                $this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in');
                redirect('login', 'refresh');
            }
            }else{
            redirect('member', 'refresh');}
        }

    }


    function auth() {
        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_database');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            //Field validation failed.  User redirected to login page           
            redirect('login', 'refresh');
        } elseif($this->input->post('usertype')!="admin") {

            $c_time = mktime();
            //$c_time = date('h:i:s a');
            $open = strtotime('Today 10am');
            $close = strtotime('Today 8pm');

            if ($c_time > $open && $c_time < $close) {
                redirect('member', 'refresh');
            } else {
                redirect('login', 'refresh');
            }
            //redirect('member', 'refresh');

        }

    }
}
```

When i try with the below link home page is displayed but styles given don't appear

http://localhost:81/sitename/index.php/login

Login page is my home page,but when trying to login it do not enter the controller functions.Any solutions regarding this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just changed my .htaccess as below by adding the RewriteBase and setting short open tag on,this helped me out by functioning the url properly.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sitename
php_flag short_open_tag on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your .htaccess as below:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Tried this but still the same

Answer (score 1):

try to run with the below url

```
http://localhost:81/sitename/index.php/login
```

Comment: that runs,but i want to remove index.php from the link,and also even if that link shows the homepage login authentication function from the controler is not accessed.

Comment: could you plz check Enable mod_rewrite in Apache

Comment: i added `RewriteBase /sitename` and enabed `php short tags` in .htaccess and den url issue and php errors got solved.